# Recuperar datos de un Fragment desde otro Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Digamos que tengo una `Activity` llamada MainActivity

que tiene tres `Fragments`

> F1, F2 y F3

Estos tres ´Fragments´ se cargan desde la MainActivity de la siguiente forma:

```
 public void initFragments(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fraOrderDetailsOrderWorkActivity,
                F1);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fraOrderDetailsOrderWorkActivity,
                F2);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fraOrderDetailsOrderWorkActivity,
               F3);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        hideAllFragments();
    }
```

Tengo tres botones

> B1, B2 y B3

Al hacer click cualquiera de estos botones se abre cada uno de los fragments, es decir, el boton B1 abre el fragment F1, B2 abre el F2....

Supongamos que el usuario hace click sobre B1 y rellena una serie de datos en el `Fragment` F1, digamos un apellido y un nombre, después hace click sobre B2 y rellena otros datos en el `Fragment` F2....
Mi pregunta es: cuando el usuario hace click sobre el botón B3 y se abre el `Fragment` F3 
¿Desde el F3 cómo puedo consultar el nombre y el apellido escrito en el `Fragment`F1  ?

Answer (score 0):

Una forma seria mediante el uso de `SharedPreferences`, en cual puedes guardar información de manera local como si crearas una base de datos SQL pero de una forma mas sencilla.

**Ejemplo**

Supongamos que en el `Fragment1` necesitas tomar la información que recibe un `EditText`, para guardarlo haces lo siguiente:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("nombre_dato", valor);
editor.apply();
```

Luego, en el `Fragment3` puedes recuperar esa información de la siguiente manera:

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String dato = sharedPreferences.getString("nombre_dato","No hay dato");//"No hay dato" es el valor por defecto que mostrara si no se encuentra el dato guardado
```

Comment: gracias me lo había planteado pero quizas hay otras opciones